# How to decide which MongoDB binary to install on MacOS?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

The official documentation of MongoDB provides two commands for downloading binaries:

1. `brew install mongodb`
2. `brew install mongodb --with-openssl`

I want to know what are the differences between the two of them. Primarily, I would like to understand which binary should I download under what scenarios?

Comment: `brew info mongodb` will tell you that the second option you suggest is not available anyway.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `brew info mongodb` does show an option for `--with-openssl`. I am unable to understand what you are trying to imply here.

Comment: If you see `--with-openssl` as an option, I think you need to run `brew update` as it is not currently an option on my up-to-date system.

Comment: Here are the details of `brew --version` on my system. `Homebrew 1.2.3
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 8e76; last commit 2017-06-17)`
I think my system is up to date.

Comment: Mmmm... no idea what has happened. My system shows exact same `homebrew` version but different options for `mongodb`. I am on macOS 10.12.5 - maybe that affects the versions of `mongodb` that are available.

Comment: I, too am on macOS 10.12.5. Now this is getting really weird.

Comment: Are you sure the option in your `brew info mongodb` output says `--with-openssl` on Homebrew 1.2.3? SSL is now included by default, but there is a `--without-openssl` option.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of the MongoDB Homebrew recipe include SSL by default (which matches the default downloads from the [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center)). The `--with-openssl` option has been removed and there is no longer a need to choose between versions. The MongoDB documentation will be updated to reflect this (see [DOCS-10347](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10347)).

Distributions with TLS/SSL support are recommended (even if you aren't currently using this feature) so you have the option available. Third party cloud-hosted services (eg. MongoDB Atlas) generally require network encryption, and this is also one of the recommendations in the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for protecting your own deployments.

Comment: This helped me a lot. It's in October.. Wonder why the issue hasn't been resolved yet

Comment: @ViscountWathika The `--with-openssl` option is ignored by recent versions of Homebrew. Using this option will generate a warning but doesn't prevent installation, so the DOCS issue hasn't had any special priority in the backlog. However, the issue should be resolved soon as I recently assigned to myself :).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need TLS/SSL support?

- If the answer is "no", use command 1.
- If the answer is "I don't know", use command 1.
- If the answer is "yes", use command 2.

Command 1 will download MongoDB pre-compiled binaries, that don't include TLS/SSL support. Command 2 will compile MongoDB source code with TLS/SSL support, which is useful if you want the communication between your application and MongoDB to be encrypted, or if you're trying to access a database that only accept encrypted connections.

Command 1 will be much faster than command 2 since it will only fetch binaries rather than compiling plenty of stuff.

Comment: Recent versions of Homebrew include SSL by default, so there is no longer a need to choose ;)